# Add projection imported .asc file

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, rasterio, earthpy

I'm trying to import an .asc file in python to clip it with a shapefile. For the clipping I'll use:

```
import earthpy.clip as cl
clip = cl.clip_shp(shp_file, asc_file)
```

However this won't work since my .asc doesn't have a CRS. This is how the header of the .asc looks like:

```
ncols         1900
nrows         1400
xllcorner     182900
yllcorner     326300
cellsize      10
NODATA_value  -999.990
```

This is how I import the .asc file

```
import rasterio as rio
asc_loc = r'file.asc'
raster = rio.open(asc_loc)
print(raster.crs)
```

The print shows `none`

**Question**: how can I add a the CRS to an imported .asc file? (Preferably with rastario or geopandas.)

Comment: Do you know the .asc coordinate system? For example, EPSG code?

Comment: An asc. file can be plotted without projection right? But I think it's: EPSG: 19914 (Dutch coordinate system)

Comment: Right and provided your raster and shapefile have the same CRS, you can also clip without adding a CRS to the raster. Nevertheless, I'm going to give the answer for the given EPSG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a CRS to a raster

```
import rasterio.crs

crs = rasterio.crs.CRS({"init": "epsg:19914"})  
with rasterio.open('/path/to/file.format') as src:
    src.crs = crs
print (src.crs)
```

If that doesn't work, and since the CRS will never be saved to an *asc*.file,

better use  [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) first, from the command line, to convert to Geotiff, before using the raster with `rasterio`:

```
gdal_translate -of "GTiff" -a_srs EPSG:19914 in.asc out.tif
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code combined with your answer I managed to convert the .asc file into a geotiff and adding a CRS.

Comment: I found I had to pass the crs as a parameter in the open() function, like `with rasterio.open('/path/to/file.format', crs="EPSG:19914") as src:`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a `.prj` file.

If you have the .prj file, it should be stored along with your `.asc` file having same name

```
raster_image.asc
raster_image.prj
```

[`.prj`](https://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/Vsample/ESRI_PRJ_File.htm) file will contain the spatial reference information.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't